# Datatable C# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datatable, format

My code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
int socot = dt.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < socot; i++)
{
    String dn = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    String gduan = "SELECT tennha FROM duannha WHERE id=@id";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = gduan;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dn);
    String gtennha = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    dt.Rows[i][1] = gtennha;
}
```

When I run code, I received an error. Please help me fix it.

[image: error]

Comment: You want to put String into Int32 variable. Then convert it first using Int32.Parse.

Comment: If you look at the error message you will notice that the return value of the ExecuteScalar is not something that could be assigned to a column of type integer. So something is really broken here. Or you have choosen an invalid column from your datatable (the column at index 1) or you should get a different value from your query or you are trying to assign the return value of your query at the wrong column (still the column at index 1)

Comment: Dont forget the `using` block for `cmd`

Comment: This shouldn't be a separate query in the first place. This is what JOINs are for.

Answer (score 1):

> Expected Type as Int32

If `gtennha` contains a number, you can parse it to an `int`. With more safeguards:

```
var gtennha = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
try 
{
   if(gtennha != null)
      dt.Rows[i][1] = int.Parse(gtennha.ToString());
   else 
      Console.WriteLine("Error: Query didn't return a result.");
} 
catch(FormatException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error: Couldn't parse 'gtennha' to a number.");
   /* more error handling */
}
```

Comment: try parse more safer than parse

Answer (score 1):

Parse string to int

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        int socot = dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < socot; i++)
        {
            String dn = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            String gduan = "SELECT tennha FROM duannha WHERE id=@id";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = gduan;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dn);
            String gtennha = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            int a;
            int.TryParse(gtennha, out a);
            dt.Rows[i][1] = a;
        }
```

**Update**

if `gtennha` always start with `VIOFFICE` or a word something like that then use this way split string

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        int socot = dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < socot; i++)
        {
            String dn = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            String gduan = "SELECT tennha FROM duannha WHERE id=@id";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = gduan;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dn);
            String gtennha = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            int a;
            int.TryParse(gtennha.Split(' ')[1], out a);
            dt.Rows[i][1] = a;
        }
```

Comment: But "gtennha" had value "VIOFFICE 124".

Comment: @ngocuong always begin with VIOFFICE ?

Comment: Format of column duan. INT32 to String :)

Comment: This conversion `String dn = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()` no need but  `String gtennha = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` needed because its contain string with number

Answer (score 0):

I think you have choosen the wrong column to assign the return value of your ExecuteScalar query. From your error message it is clear that the return value is a string "VI BUILDING 29BD" (or something like that) and you are trying to assing that value to the same column `dt.Rows[i][1]` that you have used as the source for the ID parameter. This of course cannot be correct.

So you need to identify what is the column that you want to assign the return value of the ExecuteScalar and take extra care on handling that return value that could be NULL if there is no match on the WHERE clause

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
int socot = dt.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < socot; i++)
{
    String dn = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    String gduan = "SELECT tennha FROM duannha WHERE id=@id";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = gduan;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dn);
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    // SUPPOSE THAT YOU WANT TO ASSIGN AT COLUMN 2 NOT STILL AT COLUMN 1
    if(result != null)
         dt.Rows[i][2] = gtennha;
}
```